# Как изменить стиль обратно нажатием другой кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transform

```
<div class="back" id="my-card-back">
    <button id="back-home">На главную</button>
</div>
```

```
let front = document.getElementById('my-card-front');
let back = document.getElementById('my-card-back');
let firBut = document.getElementById('authorise');
let secBut = document.getElementById('back-home');

firBut.onclick = function() {
    front.style.cssText = 'transform: rotateY(180deg)';
    back.style.cssText = 'transform: rotateY(360deg)';
}
secBut.onclick = function() {
    front.style.cssText = 'transform: rotateY(0deg)';
    back.style.cssText = 'transform: rotateY(180deg)';
}
```

Есть карточка(блок), которую я вращаю на 180 градусов нажатием одной кнопки. Хочу добавить ещё одну кнопку, чтобы было обратное вращение. Делал с одной кнопкой через добавление стиля, с помощью toggle(), но мне такой вариант не подходит.
Когда сейчас нажимаю на первую кнопку, всё отлично разворачивается, но при нажатии на вторую страница просто перезагружается. HTML проверил, опечаток нету. Ошибок тоже не выдает.
В конце заметно, что карточка начинает вращаться, но страница всё равно перезагружается.
Как это исправить?

Comment: вероятнее всего, вы реализуете кнопки через ссылки. Пожалуйста, либо добавьте небольшое воспроизводимое демо, либо, если я прав насчет ссылок, используйте event.preventDefault(), в обработчике клика

Comment: Приведенный код в вопросе не может привести к перезагрузке страницы. Нужно, что бы вы показали ваш html.